# Click to show google map in Javascript - Not working

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

This is the code im working from:
http://jsfiddle.net/X9SkK/

This is the javascript:

```
function showmap() {
     var map;
      function initialize() {
        var mapOptions = {
          zoom: 8,
          center: new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644),
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'),
            mapOptions);
      }
}​
```

I want to have it so that when I click the button the map loads, however it doesnt work for some reason. I am sure its something simple but I cant pinpoint it.

Comment: What do you mean "it doesn't work"?  There are about a million different ways that something cannot work, so please be specific. Also, what error messages are you getting?

Comment: Sorry im new to this. I click the button on jsfiddle and nothing happens, when it should load the map

Comment: `Uncaught ReferenceError: showmap is not defined`

Comment: Jason, please invest in a good JavaScript debugger. If you have Google Chrome, right click on the button and click "Inspect", then in the console you can see these error messages. Basically, this means that the function showmap is not defined when whatever is calling it is trying to call it.

Comment: Ok. I dont understand. I define it in the fuction, and then call it with the button. Where else should it be defined? I will get chrome.

Comment: You must change the dropdown menu in the top left corner of jsFiddle from "onLoad" to "no wrap (head)" or "no wrap (body)" to be able to define functions that way. Then you'll be able to call the function.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/X9SkK/27/ That got rid of the error in console but it still doesnt work :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code actually creating the map is wrapped in a function named `initialize`, which isn't being called. Remove that and you'll be fine:

```
function showmap() {
    var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 8,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644),
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), mapOptions);
}​
```

Also, be sure to specify a fixed height (such as `400px`) for your `#map_canvas` element, or it won't be visible in your jsFiddle.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you could have done:

```
<!-- Display Map -->
function showmap() {
     var map;
      function initialize() {
        var mapOptions = {
          zoom: 8,
          center: new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644),
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'),
            mapOptions);
      }
initialize();
}
```

The initialize(); function responsible for creating a map was never called. You have to call it inside your showmap function.

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/refhat/pFNuJ/1/)

Comment: I'd say it's better practice to remove the inner function, since there's no use of it.

Comment: I agree with you. I just pointed to the question owner, why it is not working.